# MySql Group by

Tags: mysql, database

Hi all so I have the following table, 't1'

```
id     r_id     o_id     count
1       2       100       1
2       3       100       1
3       5       100       1
4       2       101       2
5       3       101       2
6       4       101       2
```

What I'm trying to do is, for a given list of r_id's, return the r_id and o_id where the count is the highest (max).  So ideally, given r_id's of 3 and 5, I would get the following:

```
r_id      o_id
 5         100
 3         101
```

I've tried the following:

```
select o_id, max(count), r_id from t1 where r_id IN (3, 5) group by r_id;
```

but it doesn't seem to give me the right associated o_id.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say you want `r_id` and `o_id` as the two output columns...:

```
SELECT r_id, o_id
FROM t1 AS a
WHERE r_id in (3, 5)
AND count =
  (SELECT MAX(count)
   FROM t1 AS b
   WHERE b.r_id = a.r_id
  )
```

If there's more than one `o_id` with the same "maximal count" for a certain `r_id`, this will return them all (rather than picking one of them arbitrarily).

On MySQL 5.1 with your sample table:

```
mysql> select * from t1;
+------+------+------+-------+
| id   | r_id | o_id | count |
+------+------+------+-------+
|    1 |    2 |  100 |     1 | 
|    2 |    3 |  100 |     1 | 
|    3 |    5 |  100 |     1 | 
|    4 |    2 |  101 |     2 | 
|    5 |    3 |  101 |     2 | 
|    6 |    4 |  101 |     2 | 
+------+------+------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

this query gives me exactly your requested result:

```
+------+------+
| r_id | o_id |
+------+------+
|    5 |  100 | 
|    3 |  101 | 
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.31 sec)
```

BTW, my exact version:

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.1.34    | 
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I'd rather have it return them arbitrarily...since running this query also did not work as I expected...

Perhaps I just need to figure it out on my own.  Thought someone might have a quick fix.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: applying the query I give to the exact sample data you give I get exactly the sample results you request. Unless you clarify the "I expected" part of "did not work as I expected", you're essentially making it impossible for us to help you, right?

Comment: When I run your query on my side I get:

     r_id     o_id
      5        100

Comment: Amazing, because I do get both lines of course.  Gonna edit my answer to show exactly what MySQL 5.1 is doing (can't do in a comment, no formatting) -- please do the same to your question, also specifying MySQL release, so we can debug this weird issue.

Comment: All of a sudden it worked...however, another problem has arisen: If there is only one r_id present, it will return nothing.  So for example if you removed all of the rows containing "100" in the o_id field from the table I gave in this question, it will return no rows.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Harder than i thought at first glance - this should work:

```
select a.r_id,a.o_id from t1 a inner join (select r_id,max(count) as max from t1 group by r_id) as b on a.r_id = b.r_id and a.count = b.max where a.r_id in (3,5)
```

Comment: Alex's is nicer than mine - use that one!